# Flutter: RichText does not work with theme

Tags: flutter, richtext

I am trying to display some text in different colors. I learned about the `RichText` widget and used it as follows;

```
Future<List<TextSpan>> listOfEventsAtDay({String day, String monthNum}) async {
  final result = await DatabaseHelper.instance
      .queryForEventsAtDay(mnth: monthNum, dy: day);
  List<TextSpan> textSpans = [];
  int count = result.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    final String string = "-${result[i]['year']}: ${result[i]['title']}\n";
    textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: string,
        ));
  }

  return textSpans;
}
```

which is later called on;

```
ListTile( title: RichText(text: TextSpan(children: snapshot.data),
```

I don't want any complex stylings for now. In dark mode, the text should be in white, and in the light mode, it should be in black. That's all. But problem is, the text is always white. Why doesn't it adjust with brightness settings? Is there any way to accomplish this? Please help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style
```

Full snippet;

```
Future<List<TextSpan>> listOfEventsAtDay({String day, String monthNum, BuildContext context}) async {
  final result = await DatabaseHelper.instance
      .queryForEventsAtDay(mnth: monthNum, dy: day);
  List<TextSpan> textSpans = [];
  int count = result.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    final String string = "-${result[i]['year']}: ${result[i]['title']}\n";
    textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: string,
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        ));
  }
```

This fixed it.

Comment: related question for those who `DefaultTextStyle` is failing to help (for me, I had to use `Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416669/flutter-richtext-is-not-showing/66416670#66416670

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Text.rich` instead of `RichText`. `Text.rich` is using default TextStyle.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.rich.html

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    text: 'Welcome'
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'to the'),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Jungle',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This should be the accepted answer as it is simpler