# Flutter RichText is not showing

Tags: flutter

I have a regular normal rich text widget in a Centered per https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html within a Scaffold. I can't see it. I can't see anything. The debug tools show that the Rich Text is indeed there in the widget heirarchy (though I can't see the TextSpans within it, presumably they're in there.)

```dart
Scaffold(body: Center(child:
  RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      text: 'Hello ',
      style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
));
```

Comment: Your question will not clear to anyone. Please add code that you have done.

Comment: I said that it was code like in the link I provided, (within a centered within a scaffold), but alright.

Answer (score 10):

I tried an android build to see whether this was a bug specific to linux desktop builds. It wasn't! It's happening here too. However, the contrast ratio of my phone is high enough that I can just barely see the text in there, White on Off White. It turns out that, unlike the Text widget, **the default color for RichText text is white**, same as the theme's background, so the text wont be visible.

(Is it possible the app is responding to the system-wide dark mode theme? Nope. Switching theme doesn't affect anything.)

So, WHY is this the default color? Because `DefaultTextStyle` is bad and wrong I guess? **Use `Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1` and you will get the results you expect**.

Comment: What if I want to fix all `TextSpans` in a `RichText`?

Comment: @genericUser I believe `style` inherits? so if you set the `style` of the root `TextSpan`, correctly (set it to something other than the `DefaultTextStyle. ` one) it should fix all child elements?

Comment: A better solution is to replace `RichText(...)` with `Text.rich(...)`, you can leave your spans as they are :)

Answer (score 5):

`RichText` is a basic, lower-level approach to rendering text and intentionally does not use theme styles.

However, `Text.rich` does:

```
Scaffold(body: Center(
  child: Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      text: 'Hello ',
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
));
```